# Как работает пул потоков?

Tags: c#, .net

В .NET есть пул потоков, - это заготовленные потоки, готовые к выполнению какой-то задачи.

Но при ручном создании потока нету возможности создать поток без вызова (т.е. на будущее) делегата и более того, если поток отработал, то ему нельзя дать другую задачу.

Так как эта магия происходит?

Даже в WinApi, вроде, нету функции, которой можно было бы передать уже созданному потоку некоторое задание...

Comment: В .NET  пул потоков контроллируется самой библиотекой, вы работаете с потоками с помощью стандартных ф-ций, и не беспокоитесь о пуле, библиотека автоматически ведёт пул.

Comment: @nick_n_a это понятно. Но мне интересно, как заранее заготовленному потоку передается моя задача, если Thread не имеет для этого спец. методов, а в WinApi, вроде, функций нету для привязки задачи к существующему потоку.

Comment: Более детально кажись тут http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool

Comment: Библиотека нет - обверточная. В Thread будет передана ф-ция "прокладка", которая может подобрать любую "задачу" (как вы её назвали). Вы не видя код запуска Thread не можете сказать что он выполняет, вот в этот код и добавлено доп-функции.

Comment: Если вас интересуют детали, почитайте про контекст синхронизации потока.

Comment: Более детально - вскрывайте библиотеку дот нет дизассемблемрами, дизшарперами и изучайте.

Comment: @nick_n_a кажется понял. Эти созданные потоки просто грубоговоря опрашивают коллекцию делегатов и если что-то есть, то берут на выполнение

Comment: @nick_n_a зачем такие сложности? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/threading/threadpool.cs

Comment: Нет, условно говоря, коллекция свободных потоков (пул) из неё выбирается "свободный" поток, которому даётся именно то задание ("задача"), через делегат, которое вы прямо сейчас требуете выполнить в паралеле. Выполнение выбраного потока "размораживается" (thread resume, либо через WaitForSingleObject не смотрел детально как сделано) после чего он после разморозки через делегат получит "задачу" , а паралельное выполнение подхватывает уже ОС.

Answer (score 2):

Пул потоков – это коллекция потоков для выполнения методов в фоновом режиме. Распределение пулов занимается CLR. Что бы выполнить метод асинхронно необходимо поместить его в  очередь потока, пул потоков будет сам извлекать методы из очереди и выполнять их. При наличии большого количества методов, будет создан еще один фоновый поток. Когда поток отработает, он не уничтожается, а возвращается в пул поток для ожидания следующей задачи.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoSomething));
```

Для более гибкой работы с потоками есть Task(Задача), которая может использовать так называемое продолжение (ContinueWith)

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(Method1));
Task continue = task.ContinueWith(new Action<Task>(Method2));
```

Так же у задачи есть возможность «подготовки» к выполнению + отложенный стар.

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(DoSomething), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness |
                                                          TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

«Холодный» запуск задачи

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(Method1));
//что-то делаем
Task.Start();
```

«Горячий» запуск задачи

```
Task.Run(new Action(Method));
```

Выполнение в основном потоке

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(Method));
Tast.RunSynchronously();
```

ну и нововведение ValueTask - обертка над самой задачей

```
System.Treading.Tasks.Extensions
```

Как – то так вот…